# Joomla 3: How do I use the raw format without adding format=raw to the URL?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I would like to load view.raw.php as a raw view just like if I has appended view=raw to the URL. But I would like to do it without adding view=raw to the URL.

I have tried the following inside my main controller and none work:

First I tried this:

```
JFactory::$document = null;
JFactory::getDocument();
```

Then I tried this:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$input->set('format', 'raw');
```

And this:

```
$_REQUEST['format'] = 'raw';
```

And this:
    $urlparams['format']='raw';
    $urlparams[]=array('format' => 'raw');

And this:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();            
$doc->setType('raw');
```

None of them seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this add the following inside the controller:

```
$document = JDocument::getInstance('raw');  //this new instance is a raw document object
$viewType = $document->getType();
// $viewname below is set in jinput or as you named it
$this->getView($viewName, $viewType); 
$this->input->set('view', $viewName);
```

The above calls the view.raw.php

Comment: It can be reduced to:             

$document = JDocument::getInstance('raw');  //this new instance is a raw document object
$viewType = $document->getType();
            
            // $viewname below is set in jinput or as you named it
            $this->getView($viewName, $viewType); 
            $this->input->set('view', $viewName);

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you placed your code, but I if it is inside a template than the change is made too late and joomla already rendered in default format. Create a Plugin and use an event which is dispatched before rendering.

[Here](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) is a list of available events.

Good luck!

btw. I did something similar, using a plugin of type »system« and used the »onAfterInitialize« event.

Comment: >"inside my main controller" - thanks for the quick answer though